# an api for searching packages/libraries in unpkg like the cdnjsAPI?

Tags: javascript, rest, dependencies, cdn, unpkg

pardon if it is a silly question, I am trying to make a Javascript code editor React app and I have come across the need to add external javascript libraries as dependencies to the editor(not for the app to run, but for the editor inside it). I found the cdnjs API https://api.cdnjs.com/ which would have been perfect except for the fact that certain libraries like ml5js are not to be found in here. However if there was some way I could **search unpkg** like this, I could add particular libraries according to the user's choice. So, is there some api like that which could return a json object containing the **list of libraries with their unpkg cdns**, matching the queries sent for the library names?

Or, is there any other way I could get search from a list of javascript libraries other than unpkg?

Comment: Why not using `npm` api to get the package name and then use `unpkg` to retrieve it?

Comment: Yeah thanks, but the initial intention was to render the list of npm libraries in react, real time based on the characters entered by the user in the search field. Much like the same way how codesandbox does. I suppose using the above method, this effect cannot be achieved. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: If you look at codesandbox in the devtool you see they are using `https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/` for the autocomplete. Here is an [example response](https://ofcncog2cu-1.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.33.0)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20react%20(16.12.0)%3B%20react-instantsearch%20(5.7.0)%3B%20JS%20Helper%202.26.1&x-algolia-application-id=OFCNCOG2CU&x-algolia-api-key=00383ecd8441ead30b1b0ff981c426f5)

Answer (score -2):

There is no official way to search for UNPKG packages but there is a third part website https://www.unpkgsearch.com/

You can search for packages and directly copy the unpkg link